# Python - superimposing multiple points in space

Tags: python

In my current task I have four reference points in space with Cartesian coordinates (atoms specifically), and then a set of 4 atom groups with coordinates as well. What I want to do is to fit every group to the reference one and then obtain a changed coordinates of the atoms. The relations between atoms in every group cannot change, I want to treat it like a whole and just find the best way to fit it to reference group.

I wonder if there is any nice way to do this in Python without writing my own modules.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: is this in 2D or 3D?

Comment: Have you started thinking about it yet? If you have four reference points in 3D space then you define each one using an array (x,y,z). What do you mean fit every group to the reference one then obtain a changed coordinates of the atoms? This sounds like it could just be adding and subtracting from arrays?

Comment: This is in 3D, I have each point defined as an XYZ, I want a clean method to superimpose group of 4 atoms to a reference group. This is not as simple as subtracting arrays, because I cannot assume, that the distances between every atom in a group is the same as in reference.